# where is the jetpack compose annotation processor?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose.
Studying with codelab, I wondered that what happened to the function with @Compose annotation.
So I downloaded the androidx github and searched for the annotation handling @Compose,
But I couldn't find the annotation processor.
Where is the annotation processor of @Compose annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compose does not run on annotation processor. It runs on Kotlin Compiler Plugin, which is a lower level layer.

You can lookup the compiler source [here](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/README.md)

To be more specific, compiler plugin is looking for functions with `@Composable` annotation [here](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/compiler-hosted/src/main/java/androidx/compose/compiler/plugins/kotlin/ComposeTypeResolutionInterceptorExtension.kt)

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is what I wanna know.